# PostGIS: Find outers and inners inside MultiPolygon geometries

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to make a request to **find outers** and **inners** inside a **multipolygon** geometries. With this request I need to return a column with outers as GeoJSON and a column with inners as GeoJSON.

An image to explain my problem:
[image: Text]
Multipolygon geom contains 5 polygons (A, B, C, D, E). A, B, E are outers and C, D are inners of A.

I can find number of rings with `ST_NRings(geom)`, I can split multipolygon into polygons with `ST_Dump(geom)` but no luck with `ST_Within`.

Here is my query:

```sql
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(???) as outers, ST_AsGeoJSON(???) as inners
FROM(
    SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom as d_geom1, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom as d_geom2
    FROM(SELECT * FROM schema.table WHERE ST_NRings(geom) > 1) AS Q1
) AS Q2
```

If I add `ST_Within(d_geom1, d_geom2)`, result is true.
I don't understand how to loop through each polygon and determine if polygon[x] is inside polygon[y].
And how to return geom after result of `ST_Within`!

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719941/postgis-convert-multipolygon-to-single-polygon help?

Comment: `ST_Within` does not return a geometry, just return a boolean. To get geometry, you will need `ST_intersection`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to dump your multipolygon(s), then from generated polygon(s), get outer and inner (holes) rings. See references https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpRings.html and https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpRings.html

Then, you can do your `ST_Within` operation on each element

```sql
-- get polygons from your multipolygon
WITH dumped_multi_to_poly AS (
    SELECT
        identifier,
        (dumped).geom AS poly,
        ((dumped).path)[1] AS path_poly
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (ST_Dump (p_geom)) AS dumped,
        identifier
    FROM (
        SELECT
            1::integer AS identifier,
            ST_GeomFromEWKT ('MultiPolygon (((1.47412578077928202 34.24681845578541584, 10.31888046545486759 15.2469750590748987, 35.87039399896210057 24.09172974375048426, 24.7325547664076737 48.16911749647846364, 12.2843815064938866 37.85023703102361026, 1.47412578077928202 34.24681845578541584),(12.93954852017355961 27.36756481214884928, 13.26713202701339611 33.10027618184598452, 20.47396917748979206 34.08302670236549403, 24.89634651982758839 29.1692740997679465, 18.50846813645077304 23.60035448349072595, 12.93954852017355961 27.36756481214884928),(22.43947021852881107 38.66919579812320507, 27.84459808138610981 33.75544319552565753, 26.86184756086660741 41.12607209942197528, 21.94809495826905277 40.96228034600206058, 22.43947021852881107 38.66919579812320507)),((74.36145605264289316 36.53990300366426425, 51.75819408069418159 16.0659338261744935, 65.18911786112747109 -3.58907658421568954, 81.89587670995913982 -1.13220028291692643, 98.27505205195095073 12.46251525093629198, 78.78383339498067528 19.34176889457285853, 74.36145605264289316 36.53990300366426425)))') AS p_geom) AS b) AS c
)
-- dump rings. If path_ring = 0, outer else inner
SELECT
    identifier,
    (ST_DumpRings (poly)).geom AS geom,
    ((ST_DumpRings (poly)).path)[1] AS path_ring,
    path_poly
FROM
    dumped_multi_to_poly;
```

**Edit:** Another query to answer to comment. Be aware that we merge again polygons with `ST_UNION (...` but you can replace it with `array_agg(...` if you want an array of polygons and not merge back resulting outer and inner polygons. Note you can also use `ST_Collect(...` instead of `St_Union`

For difference between `ST_Collect` and `ST_Union`, you may look at https://anitagraser.com/2011/05/12/postgis-st_collect-vs-st_union/

```sql
-- get polygons from your multipolygon
WITH dumped_multi_to_poly AS (
    SELECT
        identifier,
        (dumped).geom AS poly,
        ((dumped).path)[1] AS path_poly
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (ST_Dump (p_geom)) AS dumped,
        identifier
    FROM (
        SELECT
            1::integer AS identifier,
            ST_GeomFromEWKT ('MultiPolygon (((1.47412578077928202 34.24681845578541584, 10.31888046545486759 15.2469750590748987, 35.87039399896210057 24.09172974375048426, 24.7325547664076737 48.16911749647846364, 12.2843815064938866 37.85023703102361026, 1.47412578077928202 34.24681845578541584),(12.93954852017355961 27.36756481214884928, 13.26713202701339611 33.10027618184598452, 20.47396917748979206 34.08302670236549403, 24.89634651982758839 29.1692740997679465, 18.50846813645077304 23.60035448349072595, 12.93954852017355961 27.36756481214884928),(22.43947021852881107 38.66919579812320507, 27.84459808138610981 33.75544319552565753, 26.86184756086660741 41.12607209942197528, 21.94809495826905277 40.96228034600206058, 22.43947021852881107 38.66919579812320507)),((74.36145605264289316 36.53990300366426425, 51.75819408069418159 16.0659338261744935, 65.18911786112747109 -3.58907658421568954, 81.89587670995913982 -1.13220028291692643, 98.27505205195095073 12.46251525093629198, 78.78383339498067528 19.34176889457285853, 74.36145605264289316 36.53990300366426425)))') AS p_geom) AS b) AS c
),
-- dump rings. If path_ring = 0, outer else inner
intermediate AS (
    SELECT
        identifier,
        (ST_DumpRings (poly)).geom AS geom,
        ((ST_DumpRings (poly)).path)[1] AS path_ring,
        path_poly
    FROM
        dumped_multi_to_poly
)
SELECT
    identifier,
    ST_UNION (geom) FILTER (WHERE path_ring = 0 ) AS outers,
    ST_UNION (geom) FILTER (WHERE path_ring > 0 ) AS inners
FROM
    intermediate
GROUP BY
    identifier;
```

Comment: Once there are only polygons it is also possible to use http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html. But there was a need to get holes as well so ST_DumpRings is needed anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much @ThomasG77. How to create an element at the end with column outers that contains all geom with path_ring = 0 and one column inners that contains all geom with path_ring > 0

Comment: @ThomasG77, you're a master !!! Thanks you so much. I'll take time to understand your query.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using:

- `generate_series` to extract the polygons (avoids having to deal with the recordset returned from `ST_Dump`)
- SQL aggregate `FILTER` clauses to separate the shells and holes from the dumped rings

```sql
WITH multipoly(geom) AS (VALUES
('MULTIPOLYGON (((10 10, 10 90, 70 90, 10 10), (20 80, 40 70, 40 80, 20 80), (20 70, 40 60, 20 40, 20 70)), ((50 30, 80 60, 80 30, 50 30)))'::geometry)
),
rings AS (
  SELECT (r.dumped).geom AS geom, 
         ((r.dumped).path)[1] AS loc
    FROM (SELECT ST_DumpRings( 
                     ST_GeometryN(geom, 
                                  generate_series(1, 
                                            ST_NumGeometries( geom )))) AS dumped 
            FROM multipoly) AS r
)
SELECT  ST_Collect( geom ) FILTER (WHERE loc = 0) AS shells,
        ST_Collect( geom ) FILTER (WHERE loc > 0) AS holes
FROM rings;
```

Comment: Thanks. Lot of good takes to improve my SQL foo :)

Comment: Brilliant solution, should be the accepted answer. Future visitors, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21908654/1894803